# How to display an icon or image in a column of TVirtualStringTree?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

In a Delphi VCL project, I have created a simple `TVirtualStringTree` with two columns.  The first column will contain text identifying the `Name` of the data being represented.  The data record also contains a status field. The second column is intended to represent the status of the record using an image (16x16 pixel) w/o text.

I have searched demos, but have not mastered the full process for how VTV displays a node, and have not been successful in getting an icon to display in the node of a specified column.

So I have three related questions:

1. I see how the text is assigned in the `OnGetText` event, but where should I assign or change the image to reflect the current status in my record?
2. How do I get the image to actually display in the column?
3. Am I limited in size for the images, or can they be larger than icons? If so, do I need to change any settings to adjust the height of each row (if possible)?

Comment: I may not have been clear in my question. I want the node to display at the  node level within a specific column. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Added Program code

Comment: I tried adding the if kind ... line and still do not see the icons.  I also  placed a showmessage at the start of ofGetIMageIndex and found that it is not called during the creation of the nodes, only when I move the mouse into the node once the program is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign (16x16 in your case) `TImageList` to the `TVirtualStringTree.Images` property, then handle the event `OnGetImageIndex` e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1GetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
var
  NodeRec: PNodeRec;
begin
  NodeRec := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(NodeRec) then 
  begin
    if (Column = 1) then
    begin 
      if Kind in [ikNormal, ikSelected] then
      begin
        case NodeRec.Status of // check the needed status(es)
          1: ImageIndex := 1; // whichever image you need
          2: ImageIndex := 2; // whichever image you need
          // ...
        end; 
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

> Am I limited in size for the images, or can they be larger than icons?
>   If so, do I need to change any settings to adjust the height of each
>   row (if possible)

Not sure what you meant by that, because you stated you need a 16x16 images. You could use `OnGetImageIndexEx` if you need *different* image lists with possibly different dimensions. for variable height you could set `toVariableNodeHeight` in the `TreeOptions.MiscOptions`and handle the `OnMeasureItem` event. another way to draw graphics into the VTV canvas is to handle the `OnBeforeItemPaint`/`OnAfterItemPaint` for example.

Comment: I agree and did so.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image list 16x16 (Images) and use code like:

```
procedure TMyTreeView.OnDrawTextEx(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  const Text: string; const CellRect: TRect; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var i: integer;
begin
    if (Node <> nil) then
    begin
        case Column of
        cStatusColumn:
        begin
            DefaultDraw := false;

            i := 0; // assign the image index from Images list here

            if (i <> -1) then
            begin
                Images.Draw(TargetCanvas, CellRect.Left +
                    ((CellRect.Width - Images.Width) div 2), CellRect.Top, i);
            end;
        end
        else
        begin
            DefaultDraw := true;
        end;
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
        DefaultDraw := true;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Using the component editor and selecting the treeview component I can generate a "onDrawText" but not an "onDrawTextEx" event.  Selecting the event from the component generates an event for MyForm1, not MyTreeView, I am using a VitrualStringTree component. Is your event owner as shown in the code correct?

Comment: TMyTreeView is a descendant class of virtual tree view. But you're using the component editor, so in that case just copy/paste the contents of OnDrawTextEx into your OnDrawText event handler.

My sample is different from OnGetImageIndex sample above, because it centers the image inside the column.